# Creating a timed function that terminates after

Tags: javascript, node.js

I created an array of Users who have N amount of time to do something. After the time is up they are removed from the array of Users. However, I do not think this is a legitimate way of doing it, any help? 
EDIT: each user would have independent times.

```js
var allowedUsers = [];
allowedUsers.push(
  setInterval(function(name){
 this.name = name;
 }, 5, function(){
   allowedUsers.splice(allowedUsers.indexOf(name),1);
   client.action(channel, "Times up! " + name);
 })
 );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: If you need this in a database, don't toggle flags, set "expiration" timestamps, test the timestamp against the current time. If you need to clean up the array you can then do it less frequently by expired, and not worry about keeping track of all the states. If it's in memory, create a `class` for user with some methods to track it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. What is the units of time?
2. Is it just a count?
3. Is it in seconds?
4. Are you keeping the array ordered by their time slice?
5. Do new users get added randomly?

Here's my suggestion, for a simple case.

Create the array of users, and w.e they're time slices are.

```
let users = [{id:1, timeSliceInSeconds:5}, {id:2, timeSliceInSeconds:1}, ...]
```

Use [Date.prototype.getTime()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) at the start of your program

```
let startTime = new Date().getTime(); //time since 1970 in ms.
```

Use [setTimeout](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) for maybe 1s or less if you want, to loop the array every Xs or Xms. And then call itself again Xs later.

```
function check(){
    let elapsedTimeInSeconds = ((new Date()).getTime() - startTime)/1000, tempArray = [];

    users.forEach(function(user){
        if(elapsedTimeInSeconds < user.timeSliceInSeconds){
             tempArray.push(user);
        }
    });

    users = tempArray;

    if(users.length()){
        setTimeout(check, 1000);
    }
}

check();
```

Or do the array modification how ever you want. Maybe just mark them as inactive and skip the inactive ones.

Answer (score 0):

for each user you need to create an object or give a value of `allowed` . I will just create an array and make its first index's value equal to a string.

```
var allowed = "allowed";
var notallowed = "notallowed";    
var user1 = [allowed, ....]; //other elements there
var user2 = [allowed, ....];

function userAction(user){
  while(user[0] == allowed){
  // code here
  }
setTimeout(noAllow(user), 10000);
}


function noAllow(user){
user[0] = notallowed;
}
```

Comment: Each user would have independent times

Comment: i guess u could just make another array of ints and add the same way but thats a lot of arrays

Comment: yes it'd be so many arrays as you need a value for **each** user, that's how databases work